# Cyclic data properties in OWL

Tags: owl, protege

I am looking for a use case/scenario where cyclic data properties or subproperty axioms become problematic in inferencing punned entities.

Like: P SubPropertyOf Q, Q SubPropertyOf R and R SubPropertyOf P and x is both an individual and class.
where (x P "2") implies (x Q "2") and (x R "2").

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

There should be no interaction between these properties and punned entities - data properties cannot have classes as subjects (only annotation properties can), so they should apply only to the individual.

(If you indeed apply a data property to a class, you will either get the property declared as both annotation and data property, which is an illegal pun, or get an illegal assertion axiom. In both cases this means your ontology is rejected by the tools you're using, or is treated as OWL 2 Full. It is also possible that a tool might ignore conflicting information and exclude explicit declarations or axiom types; in all cases, you'll not get the desired effect.)

Note about the cycle in sub property axioms: that is just the same as declaring all the properties equivalent, son not really a problem.

Comment: Illegal assertion axiom or OWL 2 Full .. so you mean if I write (:GoldenEagle :hasAge :"3") and that GoldenEagle is both class and individual then it this axiom is illegal?

Comment: Not exactly - depending on syntax used, you might force the data property assertion to refer to the class (e.g., Turtle, Functional Syntax and RDF/XML would allow that), and in that case I'd expect parsers to throw exceptions. Written as a standalone triple (in any syntax) it would be parsed as referring to the individual as that's compliant with the specs and fairly common. It just depends on the wider context in which that example is seen.